# Scan QR code from sd card using zxing not working in Android

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

```
    String imageInSD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"temp.jpg";
    Bitmap photoTmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageInSD);
    LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(photoTmp);
    BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
    Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
    Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);
```

This is my code .. but its not scanning image.. but when I capture the same image and scan it works...

Comment: Post the code which works (capturing the image).

Comment: So if the only difference is the input image, then you'll have to examine the difference in quality of the two images (one that works vs. the one that doesn't).

Comment: okay photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); this is how i get image in on activity result for capure image.. and when i take file form gallery i make bitmap from the uri returned

Comment: As you said, it's almost the same code. So the image on the SD card might have lost quality. Is the same captured image stored on the SD card? How are you saving it on the card?